# Can I make such a panel using only Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps

I don't see anywhere how to realise such panel http://joxi.ru/D2P6yZnFppyBor clicking on marker on google map.
Is it possible without creating custom functions, css and etc.?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think what the OP is asking is if that functionality comes with Google Map API out of the box. Otherwise how one can go in creating it. The question can be improved, but I don't see any reason for downvote. @MrLeah

Answer (score 1):

Google MAP API does not support that panel out of the box.

However, you can create that panel simply by creating a hidden DIV element in HTML and display its `display` attribute to `block` when the marker is clicked. (see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple))

When you are creating a marker, you can set an event listener:

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Click to zoom'
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('panel').style.display = 'block';
    });
```

However, for the information inside the panel, you need to use few other APIs.

- [Places Photos](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos): To retrieve the photos for a place.
- [Places](https://developers.google.com/places/): To retrieve contact information for the place.